# Solve() and Assume() in Maxima

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I'm trying to solve a trigonometric function assuming positive values of the independent variable. However seems like Maxima does not take into account such assumption for the solve routine.

```
assume(t >0);
solve(sin(t) = 0);
```

The expected result:

```
[t=%pi]
```

What I get:

```
[t=0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could use `to_poly_solve` package; see the [docs](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_86.html#SEC398).

```
load(to_poly_solve);
to_poly_solve(sin(t), t);
```

which yields

```
%union([t = %pi %z0])
```

which is the result you expect.